# How to extract title from the youtube trending page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was trying to **scrape** the youtube trending page. Code is straight forward

- I only need first 10 titles
- If able to get count of likes?

**Scrape** and put the title in the json file

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
import json
import ast
import json
import os
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
# For ignoring SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
def get_soup(url):
    req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    webpage = urlopen(req).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser')
    return soup
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/feed/trending'
soup=get_soup(url)
html = soup.prettify('utf-8')
video_details = {}
#All the trending youtube links
youtubelinks = []
for a in soup.select('a[href^="/watch?v="]')[:3]:
    youtubelinks.append("https://www.youtube.com"+ a['href'])
    youtubelink = list(dict.fromkeys(youtubelinks))

for link in youtubelink:
    link=get_soup(link)
    for span in link.findAll('span',attrs={'class': 'watch-title'}):
        video_details['TITLE'] = span.text.strip()
    print(video_details)
    with open('data.json', 'w', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
        json.dump(video_details, outfile, ensure_ascii=False,indent=4)
```

Here below is the place where code keep on running

```
soup=get_soup(url)
html = soup.prettify('utf-8')
```

Comment: why my code is not working Any idea soup=get_soup(url) html = soup.prettify('utf-8') this is the place of error or not error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script prints top 10 trending titles along their viewcount (here in my language, Slovak):

```
import json
import requests
from itertools import islice
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.youtube.com/feed/trending'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)'}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

all_data = []
for t, c in islice(zip(soup.select('.yt-lockup-title > a'), soup.select('.yt-lockup-meta-info li:nth-of-type(2)')), 10):
    print('{:<80} {}'.format(t.text, c.text))
    all_data.append({'title': t.text, 'views': c.text})

# print json to screen
print(json.dumps(all_data, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```
SIMA feat. KALI - Toto leto (prod. H0wdy & Gajlo)                                1 159 647 zhliadnutí
Frayer Flexking feat. Rytmus - Rakety jak pizza  (prod. Maiky Beatz)           485 027 zhliadnutí
Nerieš - Ruka Na Volante |Official Video|                                        291 706 zhliadnutí
Dame ft. Nerieš, Separ - ZRAZU (prod. Dame) |OFFICIAL VIDEO|                     737 135 zhliadnutí
Paulie Garand & DJ Wich - FORMA (feat. Pil C & Rytmus) OFFICIAL VIDEO            346 125 zhliadnutí
VÁLKA YOUTUBERŮ ep. 3.: Z PUDLA FOXTERIÉR                                        170 778 zhliadnutí
Cennet (60) - v pondelok 6. 7. 2020 o 20:30 na Doma                              42 560 zhliadnutí
EGO - TROLLIN prod. BIIZA                                                        470 046 zhliadnutí
Franto - Všetko som ustál (Official video)                                       105 118 zhliadnutí
Majk Spirit x Grimaso - Lambada (Official Video)                                 161 237 zhliadnutí
```

And the JSON:

```
[
    {
        "title": "SIMA feat. KALI - Toto leto (prod. H0wdy & Gajlo)",
        "views": "1\u00a0159\u00a0647 zhliadnut\u00ed"
    },
    {
        "title": "Frayer Flexking feat. Rytmus - Rakety jak pizza \ud83d\ude80\ud83c\udf55 (prod. Maiky Beatz)",
        "views": "485\u00a0027 zhliadnut\u00ed"
    },
    {
        "title": "Nerie\u0161 - Ruka Na Volante |Official Video|",
        "views": "291\u00a0706 zhliadnut\u00ed"
    },
    {
        "title": "Dame ft. Nerie\u0161, Separ - ZRAZU (prod. Dame) |OFFICIAL VIDEO|",
        "views": "737\u00a0135 zhliadnut\u00ed"
    },
    {
        "title": "Paulie Garand & DJ Wich - FORMA (feat. Pil C & Rytmus) OFFICIAL VIDEO",
        "views": "346\u00a0125 zhliadnut\u00ed"
    },
    {
        "title": "V\u00c1LKA YOUTUBER\u016e ep. 3.: Z PUDLA FOXTERI\u00c9R",
        "views": "170\u00a0778 zhliadnut\u00ed"
    },
    {
        "title": "Cennet (60) - v pondelok 6. 7. 2020 o 20:30 na Doma",
        "views": "42\u00a0560 zhliadnut\u00ed"
    },
    {
        "title": "EGO - TROLLIN prod. BIIZA",
        "views": "470\u00a0046 zhliadnut\u00ed"
    },
    {
        "title": "Franto - V\u0161etko som ust\u00e1l (Official video)",
        "views": "105\u00a0118 zhliadnut\u00ed"
    },
    {
        "title": "Majk Spirit x Grimaso - Lambada (Official Video)",
        "views": "161\u00a0237 zhliadnut\u00ed"
    }
]
```

Comment: why my code is not working Any idea `soup=get_soup(url)
html = soup.prettify('utf-8')` this is the place of error or not error